# Stop Jenkins from Looping due to push trigger

Tags: github, jenkins, continuous-integration

My goal for Jenkins is to trigger a build from a github branch automatically, build the application, make a update to the source and then push the source update to the same branch.

All is working except I find myself in a loop.  I'm using the build trigger "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub".

When I push the update to the same branch from within the job, it then triggers the build again putting the whole process into a loop.

What I'm looking to do is somehow put this trigger on hold until the whole job is complete.

(I happen to be building an xcode project and updating the build version number in the plist... not sure that is directly relevant to the problem at hand)

Answer (score 3):

> When I push the update to the same branch from within the job, it then triggers the build again putting the whole process into a loop.

Then it would be best to push to a *different* branch, considering that, even if the [GitHub webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) fires again, at least it will fire a [JSON payload](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#payloads), with, for the [push event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent), with a *different branch name*

```
ref string The full Git ref that was pushed. Example: “refs/heads/master”
```

By checking the name of the branch push in that payload, you will be able to avoid the loop.

Comment: Interesting... but we need the changes to be applied to the same branch though

Comment: @NickMcConnell the changes don't have to be applied to the same branch for that GitHub repo though: you can have another webhook which will trigger another downstream repo to pull from that second branch. The point is: regarding the rmeote repo GitHub alone, you need two branches. Regarding the downstream repos (which pulls from GitHub), you have whatever branch you need (only one if you want to): you control which branch you pull from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in the same conondrum, and found the answer:

https://liviutudor.com/2015/12/09/jenkins-ci-trick-to-prevent-task-from-triggering-itself-on-scm-commit/#sthash.j7YTr3l0.dpbs

Basically you can choose the option "Polling ignores commits from specific users", and add your bot's username =]

Simple & elegant